# Email "From" Field causing DMARC bounces

Tags: email, dmarc

I am using a third party mail service to handle the contact form on my website. The `To` email address I'm using was recently switched to a Gmail account and Gmail's DMARC stuff is a lot more strict than my previous email provider, thus any emails being sent from Yahoo addresses get bounced, for example. The pseudocode for my email script is as follows:

```
var sent = mail.send({
  ["To"]   = "Company Name <company@gmail.com>",
  ["From"] = string.format("%s <%s>", params.name, params.email),
  ["Body"] = params.body
})
```

The (now) obvious issue here is that I was using the customer's email address in the `From` field and Gmail noticed that my mail provider is not Yahoo, as an example, so it bounces the email. I've learned that I should be putting the customer's email in the `Reply-To` field to get around the DMARC issue, however this raises another question: What exactly am I supposed to put in `From`, a required field?

Answer (score 0):

The From field is indeed a required field and should hold an address that your server is authorised to send from. [RFC 5322, section 3.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6) explains that the from field should occur at least once and not more than once.

> In all cases, the "From:" field SHOULD NOT contain any mailbox that
> does not belong to the author(s) of the message.

Depending on your requirements, you may use an address in the 3rd party mail server domain or register your own domain.